# Jquery Tabs - going from external page(tab) back to tabs of one page again

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-tabs

Here is how I have done it, when at page containing all the tabs, I can go to tab 1, tab 2 etc. But when Im going to link Testpage, I would like to go to tab1 and tab2 etc. again without going to the tabpage. I I want to have one meny that I can include in all pages.

```
<li class="active" id="information_btn"><a href="#" title="" class="not_link">tab1</a></li>
<li><a href="testpage.php" title="">Testpage</a></li>
<li id="dns_btn"><a href="#" class="not_link" title="">Tab2</a></li>


$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('li#information_btn').click(function(){
        $('ul.submenu-accounts > li').removeClass('active');
            $('div.tab_selected').removeClass('tab_selected');
        $('div.tab_content').hide();
        $('div#information_tab_content').show();
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
    $('li#dns_btn').click(function(){
        $('ul.submenu-accounts > li').removeClass('active');
        $('div.tab_selected').removeClass('tab_selected');
        $('div.tab_content').hide();
        $('div#nameservers_tab_content').show();
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
    $('a.not_link').click(function(event){event.preventDefault();});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a conditional statement to check the `href` attribute. Then use `.load()` if it's a url to display to content `div`.

Comment: Can you please advice more, I have now tried for 40 min. it is just one page I want it to load tabs from.

Comment: It ain't pretty but it's commented and is a good starting point for you. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bobthyasian/ga5aT/)